# Chef hostname will not set

Tags: chef-infra, hostname

I have read the docs on chef hostname resource and I also have found the community cookbook which has examples of how it works since the hostname resource used to be a community cookbook but is no longer.

Different variations I have tried:

`hostname node.name`

`hostname 'myhostname '`

```
hostname 'set_hostname' do
  hostname 'myhostname'
  action :set
end
```

None have worked and I can't seem to find anything recent for how to get this to work.

Comment: What distribution are you using? Also, please add chef log output to your question, at least part related to the hostname resource.

Comment: @SzymonSzypulski I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and the log shows nothing useful so  didn't include it. If it shows something useful in the future I'll add it but until then it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in https://docs.chef.io/resource_hostname.html doc
`hostname` resource works in "New in Chef Client 14.0.

Also, after giving it a try, it seems work for me at least. See the following logs:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ hostname
ubuntu-xenial
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ curl -O https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef/14.5.33/ubuntu/18.04/chef_14.5.33-1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i chef_14.5.33-1_amd64.deb
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 51.6M  100 51.6M    0     0  3431k      0  0:00:15  0:00:15 --:--:-- 3016k
Selecting previously unselected package chef.
(Reading database ... 54150 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack chef_14.5.33-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chef (14.5.33-1) ...
Setting up chef (14.5.33-1) ...
Thank you for installing Chef!
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ mkdir -p cookbooks/sethostname/recipes
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ vim cookbooks/sethostname/recipes/default.rb
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ echo "hostname 'example'" > cookbooks/sethostname/recipes/default.rb
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ cat cookbooks/sethostname/recipes/default.rb
hostname 'example'
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo chef-client -z -o sethostname
[2018-10-22T04:31:22+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 14.5.33
[2018-10-22T04:31:24+00:00] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
[2018-10-22T04:31:24+00:00] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
[2018-10-22T04:31:24+00:00] WARN: Original Run List: []
[2018-10-22T04:31:24+00:00] WARN: Original Run List: []
[2018-10-22T04:31:24+00:00] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[sethostname]]
[2018-10-22T04:31:24+00:00] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[sethostname]]
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["sethostname"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - sethostname (0.0.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Recipe: sethostname::default
  * hostname[example] action set
    * ohai[reload hostname] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
    * execute[set hostname to example] action run
      - execute /bin/hostname example
    * file[/etc/hosts] action create
      - update content in file /etc/hosts from 7ea6de to fb5e96
      --- /etc/hosts    2018-10-22 04:27:39.004000000 +0000
      +++ /etc/.chef-hosts20181022-1725-1ghvofd 2018-10-22 04:31:24.503686000 +0000
      @@ -8,5 +8,5 @@
       ff02::2  ip6-allrouters
       ff02::3  ip6-allhosts
       127.0.1.1    ubuntu-xenial   ubuntu-xenial
      -
      +10.0.2.15 example example
    * execute[hostnamectl set-hostname example] action run
      - execute hostnamectl set-hostname example
    * ohai[reload hostname] action reload/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ohai-14.5.4/lib/ohai/plugins/windows/filesystem.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant CONVERSION_STATUS
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ohai-14.5.4/lib/ohai/plugins/windows/filesystem.rb:26: warning: previous definition of CONVERSION_STATUS was here

      - re-run ohai and merge results into node attributes

  Converging 1 resources
  * hostname[example] action set
    * ohai[reload hostname] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
    * execute[set hostname to example] action run (skipped due to not_if)
    * file[/etc/hosts] action create (skipped due to not_if)
    * execute[hostnamectl set-hostname example] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
[2018-10-22T04:31:24+00:00] WARN: Skipping final node save because override_runlist was given
[2018-10-22T04:31:24+00:00] WARN: Skipping final node save because override_runlist was given

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 5/11 resources updated in 01 seconds
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ hostname
example
```

If you are using older version, please check this cookbook https://github.com/kigster/set-hostname-cookbook

Comment: I only installed my chef about a month or two ago guess it is already far out of date. I'll upgrade and see if that solves it thanks

Comment: @JoshKirby Right. Also, you could follow along the log I provided for instructions to see if it works.